# 2-Stage login with ASP.NET MVC 5 / Identities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

let me preface this by saying that this system is already designed in classic asp and being used extensively, I'm just trying to reason about how to port it over to a MVC model.

My company services other companies which all have users- there is a company login and then once they do that there is a user login. Basically they login twice, once for the company and once for the user. I know what you're thinking, why not just make everyone login with their e-mail address? Well some companies use the same e-mail for each user account..also like I said this is pretty legacy so a lot of things kind of expect this to be the way it is.

SO, is there a way to design this sort of thing with the new MVC Identity framework? If there isn't, how would you recommend solving this issue?

I don't really have sample code because I don't know where to begin here. Anything I try to google just comes up with login + a phone authentication or something which is not the 2-stage login I'm talking about.

Comment: No. You're gonna have to roll your own heavily customised version.

Comment: Is there any way to leverage new functionality to help out at least? I like a lot of what I see.

Comment: Uhhhhhhhhhhhhhh... If it were me I would be doing it a totally different way, so I'm not sure.

Comment: I guess I should mention the way I'd solve this is to create a site as a project template that you can host as a subdomain for each company you provide the service for, that way you can probably get away with less changes to your custom provider.

Comment: I'm talking with my manager and we might just try to update the accounts using all one e-mail...we know it'd be better and much less of a headache. Especially if it isn't even possible with Identity framework.

Comment: If you can design it such that you ask for the company and user credentials at the same time, you can readily customize Identity's SignInManager methods such as SignInAsync